# Handling checkboxes and getting values

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to MVC and I'm having a hard understanding how to get the values (basically the IDs) to checkboxes that I'm generating. Here are my checkboxes:

```
<div id='myCheckboxDiv'>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)">Check All
  @foreach (var form in @Model.DetailObject.DoaFormGroupDocuments)
  {
    <br>
    var checkBoxId = "chk" + form.DocumentId;
    @Html.CheckBox(checkBoxId, new { value = form.DocumentId, @checked = true });
    @form.DocumentName;
  }
</div>
```

Essentially what I want to do is get the ID to which ever checkbox is checked and save it in to a list after I click a save button at the bottom of the page.

I have run across something like this to handle everything but I'm not quite sure how to use it really...

```
var values = $('#myCheckboxDiv').find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  // get the name ..
  var nameOfSelectedItem = this.attr('name');
  // skip the ‘chk’ part and give me the rest
  return nameOfSelectedItem.substr(3);
}).get();
```

Comment: Can you explain the context of what you trying to do. If your trying to post back the values of the checked checkboxes, then your probably going about this the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to think about is the value of the `name` attribute your checkbox(es) will have. The way you're handling it right now, your post body is going to have a fairly randomized collection of `chkN`-named parameters, where `N` is some number. The modelbinder will need something similarly named as a parameter to your action method in order to bind the posted values to something useful. That's a tall order for something that will be some what variable (the `DocumentId` values).

The best option would be to set up your checkboxes, instead, as a collection, which means giving them names `chk[0]`, `chk[1]`, etc. Then in your action you can accept a parameter like `List<string> chk`, and that will contain a list of all the values that were posted.